# Switch rows and columns of dataframe, without using transpose function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, transpose

I need to switch the rows and columns of a dataframe without using the transpose function (df.T), this is the code I wrote so far.

```
def transpose(matrix):
    
    transposed = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for i,j in matrix.iteritems():
        transposed.iloc[j,i] = matrix.iloc[j,i]
    
    return transposed
```

This code is giving the error: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

After trying for a while, this is my new code:

```
def transpose(matrix):
   
    transposed = matrix.copy()
    
    for i,j in matrix.iteritems():
        transposed.iat[i, j] = matrix.iat[j, i]
    
    return transposed
```

This is giving ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers.

Changing iat to iloc, loc or at doesn't work.

Comment: `transposed.iat[i, j] = matrix.iat[j, i]`

Comment: @not_speshal That would also result in an error

Comment: Initialize `transposed` with `transposed = pd.DataFrame(index=matrix.columns, columns=matrix.index)` and then use the previous comment.

Comment: A one line solution is to do `return pd.DataFrame([df[c] for c in df])`

Comment: tried to initialize transposed but it's still giving errors..

Comment: maybe first show FULL error code and example data which makes problem - so we could copy and run this code and test it.

Comment: you're right, I'll edit the question with the new error

Comment: to use `transposed.iloc[j,i]` you may have to first create `transpose` with rows and columns. At this moment `transpose` is empty - it doesn't have columns and rows - so it can't put value in place `iloc[j,i]` (because this place doesn't exist)

Comment: I test code and first you should see `print( i, j )` because `iteritems` gives values different than you expect. You should rather get `shape` and use two for-loops with `range(widht)`, `range(height)`

Answer (score 0):

All problem can be because `iteritems()` gives different values than you expect.
It gives column's name and `Series` with row's number and value in cell.

It can be simpler to use normal `for`-loops with `range(width)`, `range(height)`

And code need to create DataFrame with expected size before you will try to put values

```
def transpose(matrix):
    
    h,w = matrix.shape[:2]
    
    transposed = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((w,h)))
    
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            transposed.iloc[x,y] = matrix.iloc[y,x]
    
    return transposed

# --- main ---

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [ 
    [1,2,3], 
    [4,5,6], 
    [7,8,9] 
]  # rows

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

print(df)

df = transpose(df)

print(df)
```

Results:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

     0    1    2
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  8.0
2  3.0  6.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, after trying for a very long time, this is the code that works! Sharing in case somebody might find it helpful :)

```
def transpose(matrix):

    transposed = pd.DataFrame(index=matrix.columns, columns=matrix.index)
    
    for i,j in matrix.items():
        for x,y in j.items():
            transposed.at[i] = j
    
    return transposed
```